# Hide a loading spinner when you click outside of it in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I am using a loading spinner animation with a set of items.  If you click outside of it, then it should disappear. Does anybody know how to do this?

[image: Spinner]

I have tried this. It's working with `EditText`. But it's not working for `Spinner`

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    boolean ret = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    if (view instanceof EditText||view instanceof Spinner) {
        View w = getCurrentFocus();
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        w.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = event.getRawX() + w.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() + w.getTop() - scrcoords[1];

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
 && (x < w.getLeft() || x >= w.getRight() 
 || y < w.getTop() || y > w.getBottom()) ) { 
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
 return ret;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog/8384124#8384124

Comment: I already check this link. but it will be possible for a dialog but not the spinner.

Comment: You have to check the touch of your activity Window (outside of Spinner). Which I mentioned in that answer.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415970/close-spinner-on-click-outside-of-spinner

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PareshMayani, But I have tried it. Even in my activity I have more than 10 spinners. so I am looking the better one which should be apply for all spinners as the code which got success for Edittext above

Comment: Only ugly way I found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153835/customized-spinner-dialog-with-unwanted-space go through this question make Custom non model dialog for your spinner which handles touch outside of view and dismiss that dialog.

Comment: Try it and let me know about your success..:-)

Comment: Is there is no way to hide the dialog other than creating custom spinner class?

Comment: I think No. As we have to need a reference of Dialog which one is created by Spinner itself. And by default the dialog is Model dialog. So its unable to handle the outside touch event.

Comment: Isn't this default behavior? :\ I just tried it a few hours ago.

Comment: Why do you even need to press outside of spinner dialog? There is a dedicated back button on every android device for processes like this.

Comment: @SerdarS. yes There will be back button, But every time clicking back button is not so good method.we should simplify the app to the end user by providing this type of services.

Comment: Is necessary to take spinner..Alert Dialog can do this thing quite easily

Comment: @Ramkiran: did you check my answer.?

Comment: yeah, @Sameer, i tried your solution. did not help me

Answer (score 1):

What I personaly did was to create a custom `AlertDialog` with `setSingleChoiceItems()` to do the same thing. Then I used `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried it in my previous application and succeed too. But Here my requirement is for spinner. not for a AlertDialog. if you know help me pls

Comment: You can just catch the `Spinner` action `onClick()` and run an `AlertDialog` I don't see what's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution for `Dialog` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384067/how-to-dismiss-the-dialog-with-click-on-outside-of-the-dialog/8384124#8384124)

So why don't you try to create a custom dialog ([simple example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)) which will looks like a spinner? Create a layout file for your dialog with radiobuttons.

When user clicks a radiobutton, call `dialog.dismiss()` and do necessary code next

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already check the link before which you have provided.

Comment: The point is in the stylization of `Dialog` as `Spinner`, not in the link. Try to use `Dialog`, make it similar to `Spinner`