# Dismiss spinner's dialog when user presses out

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

First of all sorry for my english. I know it isn't very good but i hope you can understand me. I've been looking into this for some hours. I have created a spinner in a layout file setting the spinnerMode parameter to "dialog":

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llBarra_list"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" 
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

When user presses in the spinner, a dialog populates with some options defined in one ArrayList according to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaHashes);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

            String text = listaHashes.get(arg2);
            lblHash.setText(text);
            ArrayList<String> tweetsEsteHash= new ArrayList<String>();
            tweetsEsteHash.add(text);
            receiveTweets(tweetsEsteHash);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

The dialog doesn't fill parent's width and height, which is fine for my intentions. I need that when the user touches outside the dialog, the dialog dismisses itself. Should i create a custom spinner with a custom spinner dialog or are there some options which i can use to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415970/close-spinner-on-click-outside-of-spinner

Comment: i think that none of the solutions proposed works fine...